# No log using nlog at disk root

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm currently trying to execute a software which is supposed to log at the root of a disk like "D:\". Log file is not generated so I've made a test program:

```
namespace TestNlog
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Logger _log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("START");
            _log.Info("TEST");
            Console.WriteLine("END");
        }
    }
}
```

using nuget Nlog package (last current version: 4.6.6)
and using the following NLOG.config script:

```
<nlog throwExceptions="true">
  <targets>
    <target name="file" type="File" fileName="${basedir}/log.txt" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minLevel="Trace" writeTo="{all target names separated by comma}" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

While putting all my files generated (TestNlog.exe, TestNlog.exe.config, NLog.dll, Nlog.config) at the root of the disk and executing it, no file is generated.

If i put the program in a folder, it works perfectly.

Do you have any leads regarding this issue?
I've search for any problem related to this but without success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Windows Security - You probably don't have admin rights to write to a file in the root under the account the program is running under.

Comment: @JAZ is very probably rigth. You can also enable NLog internal logger to verify the hypotesys: <nlog throwExceptions="true" internalLogLevel="Debug"  internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log" >

Comment: Thanks for the replies.
I'm current executing the software using Admin rights. I've tried using internal logs, but the file is also not created. I've tried to create the folder to be sure it was not related to missing directories (even if they are supposed to be created by nlog) but it do not works too.

Comment: I've modified the nlog file because the writeTo of the logger node was invalid.
Even with valid file (working on subdirectory) it still do not log. (and internal log is also not created)

Comment: Manually create the file (log.txt) in the root, set permissions to the file to everyone and see if NLog can write to it. You are also using ${basedir}, so it is writing in the App Directory, are you sure you are looking in the correct place for the file?

Comment: Indeed I though it could be related to an LPO which forbid to write at the root of the disk. But Even if I try D:\test\test.log for example it do not write anything.
I've tried anyway to create the file with all the rights but without any success. I start to think executing Nlog at the root of a disk lead to this problem

Comment: Please check https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: Yep already done each step, and the avice of Jaz and Stefano were also in the same way.